# How to redirect with $location.path in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

My main concern is towards the end of this controller. At the $scope.navigate function. Basically I'm looking to see what type an 'offer' is by searching if arg.item_type == "DEAL" or arg.item_type == "EVENT" etc. My problem is to do with the $location.path. I don't know how to redirect with $location.path in Angular. Doesn't work for someone reason.

In the console it says "$location is not defined at Scope.$scope.navigate"

Anyone have any ideas how it works? Thanks

```
// BUDGET PROFILE
// A simple controller that fetches a list of data from a service
.controller('BudgetIndexCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, BudgetService) {
        console.log($stateParams);
        var loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                                         content: 'Loading...',
                                         showBackdrop: true,
                                         maxWidth: 200,
                                         showDelay: 500
                                         });


        $scope.offers = BudgetService.get($stateParams);
        console.log($scope.offers);
        loading.hide();

        // this function is done to look for the TYPE of 'offer'
        $scope.navigate = function(arg) {

        if (arg.item_type == "DEAL") {
            $location.path("/tab/deals/" + arg.id);
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        if (arg.item_type == "EVENT") {
            $location.path("/tab/events/" + arg.id);
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        if (arg.item_type == "ATTRACTION") {
            $location.path("/tab/attractions/" + arg.id);
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        //console.log(arg);
        };

        })
```

Comment: inject $location to your controller...

Comment: @wickY26 oh wow! don't know how I didn't see that. thanks. still not working for some reason :/

Comment: do you have any error right now?

Comment: @user3339063 please provide a plunker so I can help better...

Comment: @wickY26 no no errors, its just that it gets redirected to previous page and not the pages that I want it to get redirected to.. strange. maybe I have them in wrong? but I don't think so

Comment: @wickY26 got it to work. had the url in wrong. thanks for all your help. really appreciate it